# How can I add a file to iTunes, from the command line, without playing the file

Tags: itunes

I want to add a file to iTunes from the command line. I can't use the **Automatically Add to iTunes** folder, because then iTunes will rename the file, and I don't want that. I can simply type **iTunes *filename***. That does add the file to the library, but iTunes also plays the file, which is no good either.

So, how can I add the file, so that it doesn't get renamed and doesn't get played?

Comment: This question on AskDifferent has an answer that should work for you.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89234/adding-a-song-file-to-itunes-via-the-command-line-without-playing-the-file

Comment: @Kent - that answer uses the **Automatically Add to iTunes** folder, which I can't use for the reasons stated in my question.

Comment: Ah -- Somehow missed that, even though you bolded it.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Thorough scrubbing of the internet seems to indicate that no option now exists. The last version to support this option is iTunes 10.3.1, if you want to downgrade.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac you could use AppleScript to add the file to iTunes:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\" to add Posix file \"/Users/james/myMov/myMov.m4v\""
```

This works the same as importing using the GUI, so if iTunes is set to organise your media files then the file will be moved, otherwise the file will remain in it's current location. I believe that you need the absolute path to the file (personally I'd use Bash to find this).