# Add a directory of multiple files to iTunes library with Terminal?

Tags: terminal, itunes, applescript

Based on this post [How can I add a file to iTunes, from the command line, without playing the file](https://superuser.com/questions/699518/how-can-i-add-a-file-to-itunes-from-the-command-line-without-playing-the-file/1605621#1605621) which works I want to add multiple files not one.

I tried with adding a loop and a find:

```
for f in ./*.m4a; do osascript -e \
    "tell application \"iTunes\" to add "$f" Posix file; done

# Or... 

find /Users/filedirectory\
  -type f -name "*.m4a" \
  -osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\" to add Posix file {}; done
```

Terminal gives the `>` with no error.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript requires that POSIX paths must be quoted, and the paths for iTunes must be full path names.

For the shell `for` command, the path must be and a full path, so use `pwd`. `$f` must be quoted:

```
for f in "`pwd`"/*.m4a; do osascript -e \
  "tell application \"iTunes\" to add Posix file \"$f\""; done
```

For the `find` version (no "done" at the end), quote the `{}` like this:

```
find /Users/filedirectory \
  -type f -name "*.m4a" \
  -exec osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\" to add Posix file \"{}\"" \;
```

Use `pwd` to locate files in the current directory. After `pwd`, the rest of the command is the same.

```
find "`pwd`" -type f ...
```

Each file added to iTunes will display a line like this:

> ```
> file track id 142123 of library playlist id 25858 of source id 65
> ```